# django: default template file path?

Tags: django

Somebody told me all django apps automatically look within the root apps directory for a 'templates' dir first before looking within settings.TEMPATE_DIRS. However, this didn't work for me.

Is this not true?

I'm on django 1.3.1.

edit:

It turns out, the reason why it wasn't working inside my app's url mapping, I use a view from  django.contrib.auth.views.login so it was looking inside the app dir for auth. A possible solution is to inherit login, but is there a better way to resolve this so django will look inside my app dir?

Answer (score 4):

It's the other way around. By default Django first looks in settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS, and the in app folders. This can be customized by settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS. which default to :

```
('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
```

Details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#loader-types

But why would you want to do this?

Comment: Actually, the way it is setup like you explained makes more sense. I also figured out why it didn't work. My app, uses a view from a app (django.contrib.auth.view.login) and therefore looked in the auth app dir instead. Anyway to sensibly fix this, other than making an empty inherit?